# How to array listing index from Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
0 --> David
1 --> Alice
2 --> Jayden
3 --> Nicole
4 --> David
```

this sequence shows 0 and 4 David's records. I want to find David's records and find index values.

```
find --> David  
Situated shows list --> data to recyclerview listing
```

[i want to do](https://screenpresso.com/=ojkxg)
My Firebase ;

```
  "Node" : {
    "-L1pFRQg8anT4_-4V60B" : {
    "name" :"David"
     "note" : " firs note"
    },  "-L1pFRQg8anT4_-4V2342" : {
    "name" :"Alice"
     "note" :"note values"

    },  "-L1pFRQg8anT4_-65656" : {
    "name" :"Jayden"
     "note" :"note values"
    },  "-L1pFRQg8anT4_-sajkfhsaj" : {
    "name" :"Nicole"
     "note" :"note values"
    },  "-L1pFRQg8anT4_-jwquh24" : {
    "name" :"David"
     "note" :"second note"
    },
```

I know how to read and print data with Firebase. I know how to use FirebaseRecyclerview. But I have to find out in what order David is in the order of number. So if I called "David", it would be easy to show Davids in Recyclerview. I can do that. It is difficult to print the rank value of "David" among other data. etc 0-4

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ()
             .getreferen by ()
             .child ( "node")
             .orderbychild ( "name");
```

When I sort by name, I want to get "David" in position number and print it as "note" data and "position number".

[I want to do index values](https://screenpresso.com/=tHfR)

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? I'm not sure what you're aiming for.

Comment: Hey Hasan, welcome to Stack Overflow. As Timothy said (and others voted) it is hard to help you with the limited information you provided. There are a lot of people willing to help here, but you'll have to provide us with enough information. The best way to ensure you get help is to provide the [minimal code+JSON that will reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful). Questions with such an MCVE are much more likely to be answered (quickly).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i want to do https://screenpresso.com/=ojkxg

Comment: If you want to show a list of nodes of a specific user, you can either query all nodes to get the ones for that user, or you can start storing the nodes  per user in the database. Either should be doable if you study the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) and/or take the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). If you tried writing the code already and got stuck, please edit your question to include the [minimum code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I know how to read and print data with Firebase. I know how to use FirebaseRecyclerview. But I have to find out in what order David is in the order of number. So if I called "David", it would be easy to show Davids in Recyclerview. I can do that. It is difficult to print the rank value of "David" among other data. etc 0-4


         Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ()
                 .getreferen by ()
                 .child ( "node")
                 .orderbychild ( "name");

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When I sort by name, I want to get "David" in position number and print it as "note" data and "position number".
https://screenpresso.com/=thf is

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen https://screenpresso.com/=tHfR